# Dell t3500 Display Renders No Signal and USB Pheripherals Not Working. Is the motherboard dead?

Tags: usb, display, motherboard, hardware-failure

One of my neighbors told me to fix this pc because it did not work. He has important files on the hard drive, so he offered me $200 to fix it. I took it in and immediately tried to power it on. I was greeted with POST beeps. The sequence told me it was the ram, so I reseated them and the beeps stopped. But upon plugging in the DVI, there is no signal entirely. Also, the mouse and keyboard don't light up except for a split second when they are plugged in. Also tried VGA, HDMI, DisplayPort, different GPUs/graphics cards that I know work to no avail. The front light of the machine is solid green, and the numbers at the bottom are 1-3-4, which has something to do with the 'system board' at dell.com. Monitor isn't faulty because it works on my main setup. Any ideas?

Comment: Do they just need the data? Or just the PC working? If just the data - get it out, and get the data first before you work on the PC. Assuming the T3500 is Dell Precision PC - check the led codes [here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln288786/precision-t3500-t5500-t7500-workstations-diagnostic-lights-and-beep-codes?lang=en)

Comment: Given how cheap 1366 Xeons are, it might also be worth just snagging another Xeon just in case it is somehow the CPU. Sounds like a motherboard issue though.

Comment: @Darius He's paying me $200 for the entire system. I am currently copying the files from his 500 GB HDD onto my 1TB spare External SSD. So that's in check. You are correct, it is a Precision. It is relatively new, as he asked me to check it out when he bought it ~2 years ago, used. He said the person who had it before him told him he used it for 3 months before he bought it brand new. some things are changed, there were 8gs of ram in there instead of the stock 4g to my knowledge, as well as a Nvidia Quadro 1800. Mobo seems unchanged though.

Comment: Precision is usually on 3yr warranty. Out of curiosity, maybe check on Dell site if it is still covered under warranty.

Comment: @Darius Dell t3500 light/beep codes [here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln288786/precision-t3500-t5500-t7500-workstations-diagnostic-lights-and-beep-codes?lang=en) Newegg link with specs [here](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883158525&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Desktop+PC-_-N82E16883158525&gclid=CjwKCAiApJnRBRBlEiwAPTgmxNAoAC-vWlUBSjDRcog5-H0RqbwBOJKAqgqYzWg12ARkyxP_tAAYGxoCKWIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: @Darius it was near the end of the second year so I severely doubt that, but ill try as a last resort.

Comment: @JMY1000 the Xeon is an Intel Xeon W3503, and I doubt its broken as the PC's power button is solid green and seems to boot. I reset the bios, but the problem doesn't differ.

Comment: @C͝͡e̷͢pt̡̕i̴̸͘u͜͠͝m For [$2.49](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Intel-Xeon-E5502-1-86GHz-4MB-Cache-LGA1366-Dual-Core-Processor-SLBEZ/263352921150?hash=item3d510eac3e:g:rO8AAOSwsYpaH3U7), it seems like you might as well just to try it.

Comment: @JMY1000 that is a different model than stock, it runs at a different Gz and is an e5502. [here](https://www.ebay.com/p/Dell-Intel-Xeon-W3503-2-4GHz-Dual-Core-M083N-Processor/74089389) is the one for this PC.

Comment: @C͝͡e̷͢pt̡̕i̴̸͘u͜͠͝m Right, but if it is a CPU issue, you can diagnose it as such for only $2.49, then buy the correct CPU. If it isn't, you've eliminated that as a cause with relatively little cost.

Comment: @JMY100 Just read its compatible with the mobo. I will buy it and test although I am almost convinced now that the mobos Ko'd. Trying to get as much profit out of this as possible. Every dollar counts to help with my college expenditures. Or maybe a new i9 for my main...